# Mailing with smtp through website in php

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I have a code for sending emails through PHP via **Gmail** SMTP.

But when I submit it has an error, it is being failed from sending.

So can someone help me with the code?

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $exp=$_POST['exp'];

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$username = "email@gmail.com";
$password = "password";
$port = "465";
    $to = "me@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $message = " Name: " . $name ."\r\n Email: " . $email . "\r\n Number: " . $phone . "\r\n Driving Experience:" . $exp ;

    $from = "" .$name. "( Driver )";
    $headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"; 
    if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    {
      $text = "<span style='color:blue; font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; margin: 10px;'>Your Message was sent successfully !</span>";
    }
    else
    {
        $text = "<span style='color:red; font-size: 35px; line-height: 40px; margin: 10px;'>Failed to send your request. Please try again Later.</span>";
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please tell what is the exact error?

Comment: Let me just telepathically retrieve what this error says to help you figure out your issue!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: the error shows my coding:- `Failed to send your request. Please try again Later`.

Comment: I read that too, but I need help with this coding, what should be added and deleted

Comment: The problem might not be with the code, Have you setup the gmail configurations properly? there are permissions required.

Comment: Yes from that email I send emails from other websites too and they are working properly...

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23193623/7378695

Comment: @SaquibLari I am trying to use as you suggested, but how to remove, [see image](http://imgur.com/a/pEhcL)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter are you there for helping out?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton are you there for helping out?

Comment: @BabaluPandey If you take away the `@` symbol you would stop surpressing errors for your mail send and you would probably actually get something useful.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I am trying to use as SaquibLari suggested, but how to remove, [see image](http://imgur.com/a/pEhcL)